# Access ansible inventory host vars in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory that looks like this

```
[test_app_servers]
testsrv1 version=1.23 project=A
testsrv2 version=1.44 project=B
testsrv3 version=2.1.37 project=C
```

Now, I'm setting up a playbook that will install applications on these different hosts, with specific version and DB called after a project. I'm trying to access them via following var in my playbook

```yaml
vars:
  version: "{{hostvars['test_app_servers'].version}}"
  project: "{{hostvars['test_app_servers'].project}}"
```

I'm getting following:

```
testsrv1 | FAILED! => {
"msg": "The field 'environment' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: {{hostvars['test_app_servers'].version}}: \"hostvars['test_app_servers']\" is undefined"
}
```

Comment: `test_app_servers` is a group name. `host_vars` keys are host names, not groups. So you should use for example: `{{ hostvars['testsrv1'].project }}` but if your goal is just to use the current value for the current host in your play loop, juste use `{{ project }}` (i.e. you don't need to redeclare in vars, just use it).

Comment: I was trying to define environment on each host to be different (depending on the version that is to be used):
environment;
  PATH: "/nfs/tool/{{version}}:{{ansible_env.PATH}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your inventory `test-inv.ini`

```
[test_app_servers]
testsrv1 version=1.23 project=A
testsrv2 version=1.44 project=B
testsrv3 version=2.1.37 project=C
```

The following playbook `test.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: test_app_servers
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "I'm currently running from {{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - "version is {{ version }}"
          - "project is {{ project }}"
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i test-inv.ini test.yml 

PLAY [test_app_servers] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testsrv1] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm currently running from testsrv1",
        "version is 1.23",
        "project is A"
    ]
}
ok: [testsrv2] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm currently running from testsrv2",
        "version is 1.44",
        "project is B"
    ]
}
ok: [testsrv3] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm currently running from testsrv3",
        "version is 2.1.37",
        "project is C"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
testsrv1                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
testsrv2                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
testsrv3                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: That is working! thanks!